# Meaning of TLS session timeout

Tags: tls, openssl

In openssl, the default session timeout is set to 300 seconds.

But, what does this actually mean?
What happens if you do a session resumption, before the 300 seconds are over?
Is this session timer reset again to 300 seconds?
[For me, this would be strange because you could go on forever.]

Or, is this 300 seconds a hard timeout for the session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cite from [SSL_get_default_timeout](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_default_timeout.html):

> Whenever a new session is negotiated, it is assigned a timeout value, after which it will not be accepted for session reuse.

In other words:

1. The timeout gets assigned when the session gets **created**, not when the session gets used. This means the timeout will not be reset ever.
2. After the timeout the session will no longer be accepted for reuse. Note that this does not mean that a current session will be shutdown, only that a new handshake with this session will not result in a session reuse.